# Mostrar todas as cartas em Game em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Conseguir encontrar um jogo da memoria em Javascript e fiz algumas alteração como você podem ver no [meu repositório](https://github.com/wladyband/game_de_memoria_javascript/tree/master/memory-card)

O que eu gostaria de fazer é que ao iniciar o Jogo ele mostrasse todas as imagens e depois de 3 segundos escondesse as imagens como estava configurado antes, porém não sei fazer isso, alguém poderia se disponabilizar para ver como fazer modificação no código.

[Código](https://github.com/wladyband/game_de_memoria_javascript/blob/master/memory-card/js/main.js)

Esse pedaço do código esconde faz o efeito de virar as imagens;

```
function flip(n) {
    isPlaying && ($(n).css("pointer-events", "none"), $(n).toggleClass("flipped"), playSound("flip"), current ? ($(".card").css("pointer-events", "none"), current.attr("data") != $(n).attr("data") ? setTimeout(function() {
        current.toggleClass("flipped"), $(n).toggleClass("flipped"), current = null, playSound("incorrect"), isPlaying && $(".card").css("pointer-events", "auto")
    }, 600) : (point++, $(n).find("img").css({
        "-webkit-box-shadow": "0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(240,240,140,0.75)",
        "-moz-box-shadow": "0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(240,240,140,0.75)",
        "box-shadow": "0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(240,240,140,0.75)"
    }), current.find("img").css({
        "-webkit-box-shadow": "0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(240,240,140,0.75)",
        "-moz-box-shadow": "0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(240,240,140,0.75)",
        "box-shadow": "0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(240,240,140,0.75)"
    }), setTimeout(function() {
        $(n).css("opacity", "0").attr("onclick", "").children().children("img").css("cursor", "default"), current.css("opacity", "0").attr("onclick", "").children().children("img").css("cursor", "default"), current = null, playSound("correct"), point == numberCards ? (document.getElementById("bg-music").load(), playSound("win"), stopGame(), openModal("win")) : $(".card").css("pointer-events", "auto")
    }, 600))) : current = $(n))
}
```

Esse pedaço do código esconde as imagens

```
function loadContent() {
    $(".progressbar").css("display", "none"), cards = shuffle(cards);
    for (var n = "", e = 0; e < cards.length; e++) n += '<div class="grid"><div class="card" data="' + cards[e] + '" onclick="flip(this)"><div class="front"><img src="img/back.jpg"/></div><div class="back"><img src="img/' + cards[e] + '.jpg"/></div></div></div>';
    $(".content").html(n), openModal("begin")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadContent() {
        $(".progressbar").css("display", "none"), cards = shuffle(cards);
}
 setTimeout(function(){ 
         for (var n = "", e = 0; e < cards.length; e++){
                 n += '<div class="grid"><div class="card" data="' + cards[e] + '" onclick="flip(this)"><div class="front"><img src="img/back.jpg"/></div><div class="back"><img src="img/' + cards[e] + '.jpg"/></div></div></div>';
            $(".content").html(n), openModal("begin")
        }          
    }, 3000);
```

Isso vai fazer que as cartas sejam escondidas apos 3 segundos
Talvez tenha que adicionar jquery ao seu projeto

Comment: Não funcionou, que biblioteca jquery devo adicionar ao meu projeto?

Comment: pode ser que esteja dando errado também por causa do local aonde estou colocando o código, posso colocar em qualquer parte no código?